# Unable to connect to Docker container from host

Tags: docker

Just using Docker for the first time so I'm probably making a rookie mistake, but here goes. I am trying to use the `reactioncommerce/reaction` image, and it appears to run correctly. However, I cannot seem to connect to the server from the host.

I am running `docker run -p :8080 -it reaction` as suggested on the [Docker Hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/reactioncommerce/reaction/), then trying to access it by going to `http://localhost:8080` on a browser on the host, but no connection can be made. Where am I going wrong?

I'm running on a Linux Mint host.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think your problem will be your `-p` ([publish](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)) flag. Assuming your container is actually listening on port 8080 - try `-p 8080:8080` which will map localhost:8080 to your container. (Well, technically it'll map `0.0.0.0:8080` which is all addresses - including external)

But I think if you're not specifying something on the left hand side, you're getting a random port number mapped - you should be able to see this in [`docker ps`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) or using the [`docker port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/) command.

When you run `docker run -it` you start it interactively - and it should start 'whatever is defined in the docker file' unless you specify otherwise. I assume this will be a service you want, but I don't know that app. You can also use the `-d` flag, that runs the container in the background.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this command will work:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080 -it reaction
```

I tried to do the same thing with a local webserver, but wasn't able to connect to my container using `localhost` until I added the address `127.0.0.1` to my `-p` command.

Your `/etc/hosts` file should have the following entry:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

This will resolve the domain `localhost` allowing you to use it to access your server.