# How to connect to a running docker image on a Mac?

Tags: macos, docker

I am following [this tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#run-the-app) on using docker images, and I am at the stage to run the example docker image like follows:

```
docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
```

On the command line it seems ok:

```
>docker run -p 4000:80 friendlyhello
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

but when I try to open the page `http://localhost:4000` on a web browser, it seems to be unable to connect (Safari and Firefox). On Firefox the error message is

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:4000.

    The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments.
    If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection.
    If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the Web.
```

I also checked the file `/etc/hosts` and it contains the following entry

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

So what could be the problem?

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34707584/unable-to-connect-to-docker-container-from-host) and tried the following command:

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:4000:80 friendlyhello
```

which still leads to the same problem. I also tried to open

```
`http://localhost:80`
```

again without success.

Comment: could you try to go to 0.0.0.0:4000 in your browser?

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but the outcome is the same. I assume it's a Mac issue...

Comment: Yes, its a Mac issue. Tried it on a Linux box and works just fine. Why are apple products so insanely unusable...?

Comment: @Alex I just tried this on a mac per the instructions, and it worked fine (firefox & chrome). My `/etc/hosts` file is a little more lengthy than yours, but I don't know what the cause could be. Maybe try completely destroying & rebuilding the images? Also, what version macOS & what version Docker are you using, if you want to continue to try and resolve.